# Jquery toggle with remote loading of content

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling, toggle

With this function I open a layer and fill it with remote content. The problem with this toggle situation is that on a second click (close) it once again loads the remote content. How can I prevent that?

```
 $("#slideopen").click(function () {
    $(".slide").load("/v3/ajax/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $cam_id; ?>");    
    $('.slide').slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method to have the slide element "remember" that it's already been loaded:

```
$("#slideopen").click(function () {
    var slide = $(".slide");
    if (!slide.data("loaded")) {
        slide.load("/v3/ajax/timeline.php?id=<?php echo $cam_id; ?>");
        slide.data("loaded", true);
    }
    slide.slideToggle("slow");
});
```